# Different results in the sum of a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Im studing the following geometric sequence:
> $$a_1=1+b^2+b^4$$
> $$a_2=1+b^2+b^4+b^6+b^8$$
> $$a_3=1+b^2+b^4+b^6+b^8+b^{10}+b^{12}$$

This leads me to the following general term:

$$a_n=1+b^2+b^4+\cdots+b^{4n}$$

In this case, the ratio $r$ is $b^2$. The sum $s$ of $n$ terms of a geometric sequence can be calculated with $(1)$ and $(2)$, which are equivalent:
$$\tag{1} \space s=a_1*\left(\frac{r^n-1}{r-1}\right)$$
$$\tag{2}s=\frac{a_n * r-a_1}{r-1}$$

Substituting in $(1)$ leads to: $\displaystyle\frac{b^{2n}-1}{b^2-1}$

Substituting in $(2)$ leads to: $\displaystyle\frac{b^{4n+2}-1}{b^2-1}$

The correct sum is obtained substituting in $(2)$ but I don't see the mistake made by substituting in $(1)$ and it bothers me to make the mistake in other cases.

Any help will be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I use this formula $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^n r^i=\dfrac{1-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$.

Also it seems to me that your $a_1$ and $a_n$ in the formulas (1) and (2) are not the same as the ones above...

Anyway $\displaystyle a_n=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n} b^{2i}=\dfrac{1-(b^2)^{2n+1}}{1-b^2}=\dfrac{1-b^{4n+2}}{1-b^2}$

The mistake originates from the bounds of your sum, you used $n$ while the sum actually goes up to $2n$.